# NSMutableDictionary VS NSMutableArray speed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am using a cache for images that are downloaded from Parse.com. Images are used as the background images for UIButtons in a UITableView's cells. The images are stored in an NSMutableDictionary. code below:

```
    PFUser *user =self.currentUser.friends[(int)indexPath.row*4+i];
    label.text=user.username;

    UIImage *cachedImage = self.images[@(indexPath.row*4+i)];
    if (cachedImage) {
        NSLog(@"Have image");
        [button setBackgroundImage:cachedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    else {
        NSLog(@"Download image");
        //download code

        PFFile *userImageFile = user[@"profilePic"];
        [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                self.images[@(indexPath.row*4+i)] = image;
                [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            }
        }];

    }
```

The solution works well but I've realised that if I remove a friend I need to remove their from the dictionary and if I do that it means I will have to change all the indexes associated with the UIImages. I figure a NSMutable array will be better so I don't have to do that and I can insert and remove objects as desired. Will this affect the speed of the app at all? Are arrays less efficient than dictionaries?

Comment: Why don't you use [`NSCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/index.html)? It is ment for these kind of caching.

Comment: It's key valued pairs like a dictionary right? My UIImages correspond to indexes of an array storing users. If I remove a friend, when I remove the image I will have to reset all the indexes manually in the dictionary

Comment: You you could state the image in the `NSCache` with the username.

Comment: Just saw this below, thanks. I think I will give the cache a try also. Does it work pretty well without any setup? Do I need to specify the max cache size or can I just use it like a dictionary?

Comment: It works very well, you do a simple setup to complex. It will also handle memory warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole reason to use a dictionary is to have items accessible by a property, not by a numeric index. By using the row index, you are defeating the purpose of having a dictionary.

Instead of `[@(indexPath.row*4+i)]` use a more stable key, for example the `username` or the URL of the image.

If you want to go with indexing by numbers (`indexPath.row`), then use a `NSMutableArray`.

Note that speed array vs dictionary is something you should worry about only when you have thousands of items.

Comment: Thanks! I never thought of that actually. Makes a lot of sense. I can just use the username field as it is unique. As mentioned above, I might switch to a cache too.